# Erro ao executar programa utilizando o "args"

Tags: c#, .net, array, argumento

Estou tentando executar um programa passando alguns valores como paramentos na linha de comando porém está retornando o erro abaixo.

```
C:\Users\joao.mello\Documents\C#> .\exercicio32.exe 5 1 0 4 9 32 4
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
>   outside the bounds of the array.    at
>   exercicio32.exercicio32.Main(String[] args)

Código:

```
using System;

namespace exercicio32{
    class exercicio32{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            int l = args.Length;
            int[] numeros = new int[args.Length];
            int[] ordenado = new int[args.Length];

            for(int i = 0;i<=l;i++)
            {
                numeros[i] = int.Parse(args[i]);
            }
            ordenado = orderna_vetor(ref numeros, ref l);
            Console.Write("Vetor: ");
            for(int i=0;i <= l; i++){
                Console.Write(numeros[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Vetor Ordenado: ");
            for(int i = 0;i <= l; i++){
                Console.Write(ordenado[i]);
            }
        }
        public static int[] orderna_vetor(ref int[] vetor, ref int k){
            int[] aux = new int[k];
            for(int i = 0;i <= k;i++){
                int x = vetor[i];
                for(int j=0;j <= k;j++){
                    int y = vetor[j];
                    if(x < y){
                        aux[i] = x;
                    }
                }
            }
            return(aux);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro especificamente é que nos `for`s você está usando o operador `<=` quando deveria ser `<`. A varredura do *array* tem que terminar um número antes do seu tamanho já que começa no 0.

O código tem vários outros erros e não ordenada nada, além de estar um pouco desorganizado. Eu resolvi esses problemas também, simplifiquei e modernizei o código.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace exercicio32 {
    public class exercicio32 {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            int[] numeros = new int[args.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)   {
                int numero;
                if (int.TryParse(args[i], out numero)) numeros[i] = numero;
                else WriteLine("Dado inválido! Digite apenas números separados por espaço");
            }
            Write("Vetor: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) Write($"{numeros[i]} ");
            OrdernaVetor(numeros);
            WriteLine("\nVetor Ordenado: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) Write($"{numeros[i]} ");
        }
        public static void OrdernaVetor(int[] vetor) {
            for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < vetor.Length - 1; j++) {
                    if (vetor[j] > vetor[j + 1]) {
                        int temp = vetor[j + 1];
                        vetor[j + 1] = vetor[j];
                        vetor[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DlndjV). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qp9ngp) (não tem como passar argumentos nele). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Sort.c).

Answer (score 2):

O erro está na indexação do array, se tem 5 1 0 4 9 32 4, o **length** é igual a 7.

E nos for está a usar a condição de paragem *i<=l*, o que vai acontecer é numeros[7], como não há nenhum número nessa posição dá a exceção.

Tem de corrigir todas as suas condições para que não aconteça mais nenhum erro de indexação, este erro é muito comum em pessoas que estão a aprender a programar.

A condição correta seria *i < l*, assim **i** vai de 0 a 6 como devia.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo!